# How can I track down the cause of a 400: Bad Request web service call to localhost?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, web-services, 400

This is on Windows Server 2003 Running IIS.

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 website which is also hosting some web services.  When the site makes a webservice call to itself (localhost), I get back a 404: Bad Request.

I would like to see the actual request coming into IIS, but I can't think of a way to do it.  Wireshark doesn't work since it's localhost, Fiddler is useless.  I can't modify/redeploy code, but I can reset the machine if I need to.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked it down by looking at the IIS error log in systemroot\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR.  There I saw that the cause of the 400 was HOSTNAME.  From there I determined that localhost was being resolved to a different IP address than the one on which IIS was listening.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run NetMon on the server.  It ain't the greatest thing in the world but it will let you see your traffic.

Comment: this will work for localhost requests?